# Parsing C files without preprocessing it

Tags: c, parsing

I want to run simple analysis on C files (such as if you call `foo` macro with `INT_TYPE` as argument, then cast the response to `int*`), I do not want to prerprocess the file, I just want to parse it (so that, for instance, I'll have correct line numbers).

Ie, I want to get from

```
#include <a.h>

#define FOO(f)

int f() {FOO(1);}
```

an list of tokens like

```
<include_directive value="a.h"/>
<macro name="FOO"><param name="f"/><result/></macro>
<function name="f">
    <return>int</return>
    <body>
        <macro_call name="FOO"><param>1</param></macro_call>
    </body>
</function>
```

with no need to set include path, etc.

Is there any preexisting parser that does it? All parsers I know assume C is preprocessed. I want to have access to the macros and actual include instructions.

Comment: Cool. Now what's your question? :) I think this is either much too vague or overly broad (you can't expect anyone to write that code for you).

Comment: why are you NOT using lex/yacc ?

Comment: How does your XML preserve line numbers?

Comment: @JayD I want something existing, existing parsers/lexers for C assume it is preprocessed.

Comment: Wow, locked my question after a few minutes! Why won't you let me time to explain myself?

Comment: @mikebloch: You can still edit your question. If it becomes answerable, people may well vote to reopen it.

Comment: His question is exceedingly clear: "Is there any preexisting parser that does it?"   Why did you guys close this?  (mikeblock: I think these guys pounded you unfairly).

Comment: All: FWIW, there *are* preexisting parsers that do this to some extent.  My company provides this commercially.

Comment: Look at the libxml2: http://xmlsoft.org/

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks, please let me know if/how I can use this parser. I think clang should be able to do that as well, since it keeps the original AST for the error messages.

Comment: @TheMask didn't get you, the question has no relation to XML whatsoever.

Comment: Included headers can define macros and typedefs that radically change the meaning of the following code. It's not possible in all cases to parse C code correctly without preprocessing it. You may be able to do it in *some* cases.

Comment: @KeithThompson except in some pathalogical cases, you can at least give a list of tokens. In sane code, usually when removing the macro it's still valid code (and typedef only makes a statement into an expression, I can live without knowing that).

Comment: `#defined MACRO(A,B,C) do { ... } while()` type code--while not to be encouraged--is not so rare that I'd characterize it as "pathological".

Comment: @dmckee `#define MACRO(...) do {...} while();` is perfectly OK for parsing, and will allow you to parse the code with the macro smoothly. It's macros like `#define j(x,y) x##y` and then `j(v,oid)* v;` which does the problem.

Comment: @mikebloch: I don't expect Clang can do this. AFAIK, It runs a preprocessor before it builds its AST, so there's nothing left to capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at this [ANTLR grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g). You will have to add rules for preprocessor tokens, though.

Comment: 1) The link is dead.  2) OP asked for solutions which handled the proprocessing. You offered to let him do it himself. That is hardly advice he needed.

Answer (score 1):

Our [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) can parse code containing preprocesser elements can do this to fair extent and still build a usable AST.  (Yes, the parse tree has precise file/line/column number information).

There are a number of restrictions, which allows it to handle most code.  In those few cases it cannot handle, often a small, easy change to the source file giving equivalent code solves the problem.

Here's a rough set of rules and restrictions:

- #includes and #defines can occur wherever a declaration or statement can occur, but not in the middle of a statement.  These rarely cause a problem.
- macro calls can occur where function calls occur in expressions, or can appear without semicolon in place of statements.  Macro calls that span non-well-formed chunks are not handled well (anybody surprised?).   The latter occur occasionally but not rarely and need manual revision.  OP's example of "j(v,oid)*" is problematic, but this is really rare in code.
- #if ... #endif must be [wrapped around major language concepts (nonterminals)](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/formatters/CPreprocessorConstraints.html) (constant, expression, statement, declaration, function) or sequences of such entities, or around certain non-well-formed but commonly occurring idioms, such as **if (exp) {**.   Each arm of the conditional must contain the same kind of syntactic construct as the other arms.    #if wrapped around random text used as bad kind of comment is problematic, but easily fixed in the source by making a real comment.  Where these conditions are not met, you need to modify the original source code, often by moving the #if #elsif #else #end a few tokens.

In our experience, one can revise a code base of 50,000 lines in a few hours to get around these issues.   While that seems annoying (and it is), the alternative is to not be able to parse the source code at all, which is far worse than annoying.

You also want more than just a parser.  See [Life After Parsing](http://semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html), to know what happens after you succeed in getting a parse tree.   We've done some additional work in building symbol tables in which the declarations are recorded with the preprocessor context in which they are embedded, enabling type checking to include the preprocessor conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Your specific example can be handled by writing your own parsing and ignore macro expansion.

Because `FOO(1)` itself can be interpreted as a function call.

When more cases are considered however, the parser is much more difficult. You can refer [PDF Link](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/10856/UIUCDCS-R-2008-3009.pdf) to find more information.